# How to implement versions by country on Rails web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I need to create a web app that would be different for each country (and not only different language). Let's say the website lists insurance solutions in the country.

For example, users in France typing example.com would need to be sent to http://france.example.com and American users would go to http://us.example.com

All websites would have the same display/layout but the content in the pages would vary as insurance and companies are not the same in each country.

What I'd like is:

- in my backend: Manage multiple "country versions" on which I can work to improve features, layout, etc. in a single time without having to update the code on each version. All country versions would stay in similar stat this way.
- in the backend: create a filter that "sends" the insurance item I input in my backoffice into the right country-wesbite.

it means for example that the page describing an insurance  ALpha in France would only exist in the france version (http://france.example.com/alpha_insurance_description) and not in other country versions.

What kind of architecture must I implement? Are there Rails gems that answer this kind of problematic? (if not maybe some websites describing how to create this kind of multi-country website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"multi-tenancy" is what you want. The following two railscasts explains two different approches to achieve the same.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/389-multitenancy-with-postgresql

http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes

Also you can use [subdomain-fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu), for subdomain handling and route validation.

Comment: I don't feel like multitenancy is a good answer - a country is not really a tenant of the app

Answer (score 2):

I would just use the geoIP data (or user preferences) to find out which country to show and have the content stored in the DB (e.g. insurance companies) with a country code. Seeing as an insurance company will have an address and postcode anyway, this should be pretty simple. That way, both the content and the site language can be set dynamically.

As for the subdomains, you can CNAME all of them to your main site and use a little piece of Rack middleware (hand rolled) to redirect requests to the right subdomain if necessary. After that, the site ignores the subdomain itself and just server content dynamically. Alternatively, you could have some code in the application config that reads the subdomain from the Rack request, extracts the country code, and sets it as a config variable that you then use to flag what country code to use when showing the dynamica content, setting the language, etc.

Comment: The rack middleware sounds interesting. However I have no clue how that would look. Can yo be more specific?

Comment: Something along these lines: http://icelab.com.au/articles/useful-heroku-friendly-rewrites-with-rack-rewrite/

Comment: Added a new question as my needs have changed: i would like to seperate 'country versions' but with the same URLs and load the content dynamically as you were advising: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129398/serve-different-content-according-to-country-of-user-rails-4